# datatype image in $.ajax

Tags: asp.net, jquery, asp.net-ajax, captcha

in page `cap.aspx`

==========================================================================

```
   string code = GetRandomText();

    Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(160,50,System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);


    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap); 
    Pen pen = new Pen(Color.LavenderBlush); 
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0,0,160,50);

    SolidBrush b = new SolidBrush(Color.LightPink);
    SolidBrush blue = new SolidBrush(Color.White);

    int counter = 0; 

    g.DrawRectangle(pen, rect);
    g.FillRectangle(b, rect);

    for (int i = 0; i < code.Length; i++)
    {
        g.DrawString(code[i].ToString(), new Font("Tahoma", 10 + rand.Next(14, 18)), blue, new PointF(10 + counter, 10));
        counter += 20;
    }

    DrawRandomLines(g); 

    bitmap.Save(Response.OutputStream,ImageFormat.Gif);

    g.Dispose();
    b.Dispose();
    blue.Dispose();
    bitmap.Dispose();
```

===================================================================================

```
<div id="DIVdialog" style="display:none">
    <img src="cap.aspx"/>
</div>
```

===================================================================================

```
$("#DIVdialog").dialog();
```

==================================================================================
show dialog but does not show image? address `cap.aspx` is correct!

how get `cap.aspx` by $.ajax and datatype:image?

Comment: `pen`, `b` and `blue` also must be disposed.

Comment: Why, it does matter. True, it doesn't answer the question, which is why that was a comment, not an answer. I see it generally useful to make side notes on making a piece of code better. I would, for instance, kindly point you to the [`using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02(v=VS.90).aspx) clause.

Comment: ok, add this to my code.but still does not work

Comment: If you just add the img to a page, do you see the image ?

Answer (score 1):

I think that the key here is to add the ContentType and the BufferOutput

```
context.Response.ContentType = "image/gif";     
context.Response.BufferOutput = false;
```

Eg:

```
public void RenderIt(HttpContext context) 
{
    context.Response.ContentType = "image/gif";     
    context.Response.BufferOutput = false;

     string code = GetRandomText();

    using(Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(160,50,System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb))
    {
        using(Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
        {
            using(Pen pen = new Pen(Color.LavenderBlush)
            {   
                using(SolidBrush b = new SolidBrush(Color.LightPink))
                {
                    using(SolidBrush blue = new SolidBrush(Color.White))
                    {

                    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0,0,160,50);

                    int counter = 0; 

                    g.DrawRectangle(pen, rect);
                    g.FillRectangle(b, rect);

                    for (int i = 0; i < code.Length; i++)
                    {
                        g.DrawString(code[i].ToString(), new Font("Tahoma", 10 + rand.Next(14, 18)), blue, new PointF(10 + counter, 10));
                        counter += 20;
                    }

                    DrawRandomLines(g); 

                    g.Dispose();
                    b.Dispose();
                    blue.Dispose();

                    // Return
                    bitmap.Save(context.Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Gif);

                    // Dispose
                    bitmap.Dispose();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    context.Response.End();
}
```